# *ngIf is not working inside mat-table ng-container

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I am using Angular mat table to create a simple table with three columns. In it I need to hide 2 columns when click any row in the table. So I created a click function and set the boolean variable as true when click an row.

By using that boolean value I put `*ngIf` condition in HTML file to hide the columns when row click. But `*ngIf` wouldn't work in the Angular mat table.

Here is my code:

HTML

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dessert (100g)</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="rowClick" matColumnDef="calories">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Calories</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.calories}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container *ngIf="rowClick" matColumnDef="fat">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fat (g)</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fat}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowClick" matColumnDef="carbs">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Carbs (g)</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.carbs}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="rowClicked()"></tr>
</table>
```

TS

```js
export class sampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public rowClick: boolean =true;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  public rowClicked() {
    this.rowClick = false;
    console.log(this.rowClick);
  }

  dataSource: Food[] = [
    {name: 'Yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6, carbs: 24},
    {name: 'Sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9, carbs: 37},
    {name: 'Eclairs', calories: 262, fat: 16, carbs: 24},
    {name: 'Cupcakes', calories: 305, fat: 4, carbs: 67},
    {name: 'Gingerbreads', calories: 356, fat: 16, carbs: 49},
  ];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'calories', 'fat', 'carbs'];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `*ngIf` directive, you could modify the `displayedColumns` variable to control which columns are rendered. Try the following

```js
export class sampleComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'calories', 'fat', 'carbs'];

  public rowClicked() {
    this.displayedColumns = ['name'];
  }

  public reset() {
    this.displayedColumns = ['name', 'calories', 'fat', 'carbs'];
  }
}
```

Now the `rowClick` boolean flag isn't required.

Comment: Then what is the use of reset() here when we need to call the reset button.

Comment: You'd use it if you wish to show all the columns again. You could remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the 1st column Header Name also with this function? Here the column name is Dessert so is it possible to hide the Dessert also?